Sci-fi story with male bounty hunter protagonist
I recently read only the first chapter, as an ebook on someone else's ipad. I'd like to read the remainder. Unfortunately, it had no visible title or author. I think it was novel length, but that's a guess.
What I remember:

Money was "credits".
The bounty hunter was working solo, in a spacecraft he picked up
cheap for its worth: it had been a smuggler's ship and had much
internal work.
Cockpit had large screens, which could be turned off to see through
them to look out at space. This the protagonist-narrator described as something like "the best view in the universe" or "the best seat in the galaxy".
His ship had a brig, and at least two other cabins, one for him and one that he sometimes used for the bounty when the bounty didn't mind being taken in. He mentioned that he had picked his cabin by a coin-toss.
The story began with him handing someone over, then waiting to be paid before taking off.
The ship had an AI that he had spent a bit extra to give a female hologram appearance, which looked for new jobs for him, but found none, at least in the first chapter.

Based on the AI and the large (flat and transparent?) screens, I suspect it's a fairly recent novel.

Edit remembered some more:

The galaxy was split into two zones: the inner (populated with few dozen  billion people I think?) and outer. I don't remember the terms that were used for these, though.
The math was BAD. The ship could travel at half light speed, yet it could travel across the galaxy in days. Might've been a handwave, or even be set in a different "galaxy", but it made me wince as I read it!


More:

the AI suggested one job, but it was in a super-religious system, which would have required him to pledge to follow their religion as long as he was in that system. He noped out of that one.
There were, I think, two other ones she offered him, but neither suited him. I don't remember why, though. He was sanguine about this, saying that one of the things he liked about the career was that there was always a constant flow of new jobs coming in.


I didn't know that the Monopoly and Mergers Commission employed bounty hunters?

Lol! But also, good call: while MMC is common shorthand for Male Main Character for writers, it's not obvious. I've edited the question to avoid the term.
